# Modify a script in the R Script repository in QGIS

Tags: qgis, r

I'm trying to use to R scripts available in QGIS via the processing Panel, and in the "Get R scripts from on-line script collection". I spotted some errors in the script "Kriging" that prevents it from working. I corrected the errors to make it work, but I think it would be nice to correct the source script with the correction I made.

Does anyone knows how can I update a script from this list, except from trying to find the author and tell him ? Is there a GitHub repository somewhere that would hold them ?

Plan B would be to upload a modified script, I guess...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems someone else has spotted the same error : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Processing/issues/59

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try here:

[https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Processing/blob/master/rscripts‌​/Kriging.rsx.](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Processing/blob/master/rscripts/Kriging.rsx)

Note that you will need to sign up/log in to make or propose changes to the script:

[image: GitHub image]

Comment: I submitted a pull request : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Processing/pull/68 Hope it works :) thanks for your help.

Comment: @RobinP - Most welcome, hopefully it will =)

Comment: It's a first ! I didn't play much with GitHub yet :)

Comment: News from this pull request : "volaya  merged 1 commit into qgis:master ... 6 days ago"...  Yeah !